# Why these dicom files exported by GDCM cannot be recongnized correctly by 3D Slicer?

Tags: gdcm, fo-dicom

I exported multiple slices of the same series (and the same study) using [GDCM](https://gdcm.sourceforge.net/) in C++. The data is attached [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13xKxE014ZmDDnCrZGY8DfQ6mZDjhZaJ3/view?usp=share_link).
But it seems that [3D Slicer](https://www.slicer.org/) cannot recognize these files correctly:

1. Each dcm file was recognized as a volume

[image]

2. After import, nothing is displayed in Slicer.

I think I've filled some inappropriate content into some important dicom Tags. But there are hundreds of tags, how to find which one[s] is[are] inappropriate? How to make these dicom files compatible with Slicer?

**What I've tried:**

1. Set the same Study UID and Series UID of each dicom file. [Still the same]
2. Change to [fo-dicom](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom)(C#) from GDCM(C++). [Still the same]

**Error logs in Python interactor console:**

```
Warning in DICOM plugin Scalar Volume when examining loadable Series Number: Unnamed Series: Reference image in series does not contain geometry information. Please use caution.

Loading with imageIOName: GDCM
Could not read scalar volume using GDCM approach.  Error is: FileFormatError
Loading with imageIOName: DCMTK
Could not read scalar volume using DCMTK approach.  Error is: FileFormatError

Could not load: Series Number: Unnamed Series as a Scalar Volume
```

Comment: A quick look at your data shows that you have the meta tag `SourceApplicationEntityTitle` (0002,0016) twice in the dataset, which is illegal. I don't know if this is related to the problem, but you may want to fix this.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen The duplicated Tag would be ignored by 3D slicer (with a warning in log).  I've removed this tag and updated the data. My problem is not resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the information in the Python interactor console, it may caused by a known issue of older Slicer. Can you upgrade 3d Slicer to the latest nightly built version? I can import your DICOM files correctly with version 5.3.0-2023-05-21.  As 5.x is better able to handle non-compliant DICOM files.

Comment: Great thx! This fixes the immediate problem.

Comment: Glade to hear that. But take care of the coodinates & positioning tags. The positon information in your files may be incorrectly. You will find this issue if you goto the Volume Rendering Module.

Comment: The latest version of Slicer has solved the issue.